# When will a player begin to have a chance to receive equipment higher than Blue quality?

Tags: skyforge

At present, I have have approximately 11,000 prestige, but the best weapons and rings I have found have been blue (Rare) quality, or the lesser green (Uncommon). Purple (Epic) amulets are an almost guaranteed drop from the last enemy in Group missions, but aside from them, I have not seen any epic level rings, weapons or additionals - nor have I seen yellow (Legendary) drops for any slot.

At what point may a player begin to have a chance at receiving the higher rarities? I figure that there's a prestige lock, as there is with the Silver Pommels, which unlock around 18,600 prestige.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purple rings are dropping first in Isabella, the first raid (~36k prestige)

Purple weapons/ offhand are dropping in Distortions (~68k prestige)

Purple trophies fragments are starting to drop at (~36k) once you get to do your weekly purple spark quest. The drop chance is quite low (~1%) but you first have to get anyway a blue trophy first.

As you wrote already, purple amulets are dropping in 5er group dungeons (100% chance at final boss), if you want to farm them, best place is Targo Islands. (5 possible drop chances OR farming second boss, which takes ~2min)

Legendary weapons were part of the packages you can/ could buy, so far as far as I know they don't drop anywhere.